# fortran test memory overflow

Tags: memory-management, fortran

I am running a FORTRAN program that allocates memory dynamically for rather large arrays, and sometimes they do not fit into memory.

Thus the allocation

```
 allocate(my_array(really big_number))
```

will give the error

```
Operating system error: Cannot allocate memory
Allocation would exceed memory limit
```

and the program would exit. I would like to know if there is any way to capture this or test that the memory will be available, so that i can take appropriate measures if I'm not allowed to allocate such a big array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `allocate(my_array(really big_number),stat=ierror)`

With the `stat=` specifier, the status of the allocation will be stored in the specified variable (`ierror` in the example).  Zero means the allocation succeeded, non-zero means it failed.

From the Fortran 90 standard (ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N001-N1100/N692.pdf) on the `ALLOCATE` statement:

> If the `STAT=` specifier is present, successful execution of the
>   ALLOCATE statement causes the stat-variable to become defined with a
>   value of zero.
>
> If an error condition occurs during the execution of the `ALLOCATE`
>   statement, the stat-variable becomes defined with a
>   processor-dependent positive integer value. If an error condition
>   occurs during execution of an `ALLOCATE` statement that does not contain
>   the `STAT=` specifier, execution of the executable program is
>   terminated.

Comment: Worth to note it is not bomb proof. En error can still be encountered when accessing the array on some systems.